# Remove background noise from audio signal

Tags: matlab, python, audio-processing, noise-cancellation

I am looking for a python or matlab code to take an input audio signal, process it and remove any background noise other than the infant cry such as vehicle noise or a human talking noise and get the output as a pure cry audio signal free from any background noise and save the new file.

Comment: You should look into Source Separation or Signal Separation. There's not a single answer for it but rather many solutions, some rely on machine learning algos.

Comment: You might find [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22baby+cry%22) and [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22infant+cry%22) useful.

Comment: @CyberMen okay thank you but can you tell me about any such methods which i can use like fast fourier transform or some other method please

Comment: Sorry, there is no such thing as perfect source separation. Modern telephones are close, but far from perfect. In general there is a trade off between noise suppression and signal conservation and the problem is the harder, the more similar noise and signal are.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Do you have multiple sensors? How much separation do you need exactly? Does the interference occupy a wider bandwidth than the signal you care about? What approaches have you tried already?